# How did reanimated Haku and Zabuza die?

Tags: naruto

According to [Naruto wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Summoning%3A_Impure_World_Reincarnation), a reanimated body can die from any of the following ways:

> 1. Remove the soul from the reincarnated body, such as with the Dead
>      Demon Consuming Seal.
> 2. Have the summoner end the technique. As they are unlikely to do this
>      voluntarily, using a genjutsu to trick them into cancelling the
>      technique is ideal.
> 3. A less reliable, though equally effective method is to have the
>      reincarnated soul be affected in some emotional way that gives them
>      closure, allowing their soul to break free of the Impure World
>      Reincarnation's influence.

At episode 265, after Haku and Zabuza got reincarnated, they were faced by Kakashi and his army. At first, they were really hesitating to kill Kakashi and army and said that were under control of someone. Meanwhile, Kabuto used Mitarashi Anko to harness Orochimaru's chakra to tighten Haku's and Zabuza's soul to the body and as a result they became really powerful, a immortal killing puppet. They were fighting really hard and at episode 266(spoilers below):

> Both Zabuza and Haku got killed by Kakashi's chidori. [image]

How did they die? Neither of the above three points were followed i.e the soul were not removed by reaper death seal, nor the summoner was under a genjutsu nor the soul was affected in any emotional way. Yes, they were emotional at first but after getting Orochimaru's power, their soul were tightened more to the body which Kabuto felt that they were now a mere immortal killing machine.

> Why did Zabuza and Haku got killed by a mere ninjustsu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Haku or Zabuza were "killed" in the sense you describe. In the same episode you referenced, they were both temporarily immobilized:

- Haku was immobilized by shielding himself in front of Zabuza when attacking was attempting to strike him with Chidori
- Zabuza was immobilized after Kakashi successfully hit him with a Chodori.

As they were immobilized, this gave [Ensui Nara](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ensui_Nara) an opportunity to hold them with the Shadow Bind technique

> After Zabuza cuts through Haku, Ensui told Santa that Kakashi only caught one enemy and immobilised Haku as he regenerated. When Kakashi successfully connected his shadow to Zabuza's, he immediately immobilised him as well.

In [this Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5crWyoGnsnI&feature=youtu.be&t=540) video, you can see the shadow line holding two shinobi down. This gave another shinobi to use the [Cloth Binding Technique](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Cloth_Binding_Technique) to capture them.

[image: Haku and Zabuza being held by shadow]

Answer (score -2):

Haku covered Zabuza with his body, so he died. He wanted Naruto to kill him (Naruto had defeated Haku before, but he didn't kill him and nke wanted to do it). Zabuza was later killed by Kakashi, but before his death he managed to deal with some of the gang members and partially redeemed his guilt thanks to Naruto who talked to him :)

Comment: I am talking about 'renaminated' Zabuza and Haku where they were brought to life by Kabuto. It happens in Naruto Shippuden. The events in your answer occurs in original Naruto series.

Comment: My question has been (correctly) answered by Wondercricket. Your answer doesn't add any new information and is incorrect. I suggest you to delete your answer if you want to avoid downvotes.